# C#.net Read Visual Studio 2017 privateregistry.bin file

Tags: c#, vsix, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 now stores the settings into a Hive file which is located in users visual studio appdata. the file name is privateregistry.bin.

Is it possible to read the file dynamically using C#.net?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install nuget package [OffregLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OffregLib/). Then you can open **privateregistry.bin** and iterate over its content like this:

```
using (OffregHive hive = OffregHive.Open(@"D:\Daten\VisualStudio2017\2\privateregistry.bin"))
{
  string fullName = hive.Root.FullName;
  OffregKey ork = hive.Root.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio");

  foreach(SubKeyContainer key in ork.EnumerateSubKeys())
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine(key.Name);
  }
}
```

[OffregLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OffregLib/) is a C#-bridge to the functionality provided by [Offline Registry Library (offreg.dll)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210756(v=vs.85).aspx)

Please note that class **Microsoft.Win32.Registry** of .NET does not allow to open an arbitrary hive-file from disk. This is something which can only be done with [Offline Registry Library (offreg.dll)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210756(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you want to have nice UI to look at the content of privateregistry.bin you can use regedit.exe. You need to select the HKEY_USERS node, and click the File > Load Hive… menu. You select the privateregistry.bin file, give a name to the hive (I entered “VS2017PrivateRegistry”) and now you can see the 15.0_Config key populated as usual (note: use File > Unload Hive when done).
[Visual Studio Extensibility (VSX)](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2016/11/23/some-implications-of-the-new-modular-setup-of-visual-studio-2017-for-vsx-developers/)

Location of privateregistry.bin (VS2017):

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_c96087d0\privateregistry.bin

Comment: Hi, this is a manual way of doing. but i need to do this using C#.net dynamically on click of a menu.

Comment: I updated my answer yesterday. Please see my programatic way to read/write privateregistry.bin.

Comment: Hi, iam getting "resource locked" error message. i think we cannot read the file when visual studio is open using this method. i wanted to implement this feature for a VSIX Package so visual studio must be open.

Comment: iam getting the below mentioned error message. The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_33471a2aExp\privateregistry.bin' because it is being used by another process.